# SharePoint, How to update/edit/modify the owstimer.exe.config programmatically?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Is there any way how to update/edit/modify the **owstimer.exe.config** programmatically in SharePoint 2010?

I don't want to edit it by manually...

I want to add/remove/update/modify AppSettings in it.

for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="testKey" value="testValue"/>
  </appSettings>
  <runtime>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

location: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN\owstimer.exe.config

Thank you